# Horizontal align link inside div with table-cell property

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I align text inside div with "next" class to the right?
My html code:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="navigation prev">
    <a>prev</a>
  </div>
  <div class="rec"><a href="">rec</a></div>
  <div class="navigation next">
    <a>next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.box {
    display: table;
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    width: 100%;
}

.rec {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
}

.navigation {
    display: table-cell;
    background: yellow;
}

.nagivation.next > a {
    vertical-align: right;  
}
```

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/zhe6ctkm/

Comment: Vertical-align doesn't support the value 'right' only 'top', 'middle' or 'bottom'. Are you thinking of the 'align: right' property?

Comment: `.next { text-align:right; }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title and question don't seem to match, so I'm going to answer your question. You can align the link to the right using `text-align: right;`.

```css
.box {
  display: table;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.rec {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
.navigation {
  display: table-cell;
  background: yellow;
}
.navigation.next {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="navigation prev">
    <a>prev</a>
  </div>
  <div class="rec"><a href="">rec</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation next">
    <a>next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
.navigation.next{
  text-align: right;
}
```